# Program to assign mouse button chords?

Tags: mouse, shortcut, customization

Is there an app to assign actions (such as shortcut keys) to mouse button **chords**?

For example, button 1 + button 4 = Cmd+C, button 4 alone = Cmd+V, etc.

I have tried a few utilities, but none of them support assigning a custom action to two buttons pressed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

[Better Touch Tool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net) can do what you want, and can even be set up to do so on a per-app basis.

Comment: That's one of the apps I tested and I don't think you can program chords with it. Did you find a way?

Comment: The Magic Mouse settings allow for two and three finger clicks. I'm currently on the road without my computer; but I think there may be a similar setting for non-magical mice as well.